# install bioconductor

Tags: bioconductor

I used

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install()
```

for installing "bioconductor" but I encountered this error:

```
Error: invalid version specification ‘Bioconductor version cannot be validated; no internet connection?’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file(con, "r") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'à¿q'
2: In file(con, "r") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'pen the ð¥Xn'
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please [edit] your question and tell us: i) do you actually have a working internet connection? ii) What operating system are you using? iii) What version of R?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. 1- yes i have 2-  windows 7 3- 3.6.0 version

Comment: @Amina what is your local language and your keyboard configuration?. It might be a problem related to it. The command with this error is the install? Have you asked this in support.bioconductor.org (which is the official channel)?

Comment: @llrs I checked my system and everything was correct. I didn’t ask support.bioconductor. However, thank you for your advise.

Comment: I don't know what is correct for you, but definitely something is not correct, so please post your language configuration if you want further help. I suspect that part of the problem is from reading a string in a different encoding that the supported or something similar.